# Unable to add data to pandas without hardcoding

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in this form

```
Name               Date                        Salescount

Nanco           2019-01-10 00:25:00                 17
Nanco           2020-02-09 01:15:00                 21
Nanco           2019-06-08 02:55:00                 45
RBR             2020-06-04 05:25:00                 14
RBR             2019-05-05 07:00:00                 13
ESTO            2018-08-05 04:00:00                 14
ESTO            2019-07-05 05:00:00                 12
ESTO            2017-09-04 03:04:00                 19
```

(Note - The actual value of dates and salescount are different in original dataset, I have just added a sample)

So, I have to find the count of sales for each company for last 1 year (ie. after 13th june 2020), So I have followed this
approach:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['date']>='2020-06-13')]
filtered_df.groupby('name')['salescount'].sum()

So, it returned me table in this form

Nanco   83
RBR     27
ESTO    45
```

Now, I created a new column in this table and inserted the values manually.

```
df['sales_count_1st_year']=0
df['sales_count_1st_year'][df['name']=='Nanco']=83
df['sales_count_1st_year'][df['name']=='RBR']=27
df['sales_count_1st_year'][df['name']=='ESTO']=45
```

Although I got the correct o/p but this way is completely hardcoded. So, Can someone please suggest me better code for this

Comment: Your sample data has no values past `13th june 2020`. It also doesn't have a column `'name'`

Answer (score 0):

1st of all when executing

```
filtered_df.groupby('name')['salescount'].sum()
```

you simply print the results on the screen
what I would do is through the results into a dataframe:

```
results = filtered_df.groupby('name')['salescount'].sum()
```

Since the groupby function will make an index out of the grouped column name,
I would then use reset_index, which will move the name index back as a column
1st, make the series group a dataframe

```
results = filtered_df.groupby('name')['salescount'].sum()
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
results.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

the last step would be to merge the data together, left join the grouped data to the existing dataframe, and fill nans if any:

```
results = filtered_df.groupby('name')['salescount'].sum()
results.reset_index(inplace=True)
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
df = pd.merge(df,results,how='left',on='name')
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: It's showing error : Cannot reset_index inpace on a series to create a dataframe. Also, this code is not creating a new column. By using this code, the original volume column is renamed as voume_x and new column as volume_y.

Comment: You can skip the `reset_index` on both sides and do a `df.join(results, on='name')`

Comment: @Cimbali - the reset index is only on one side

Comment: @Rishavv - following your comment - adding a small fix. I usually use aggregate on groupby, then when a datafraem is created, I just need to reset the index...

Comment: I have a company named as TYSCO, which doesn't have any salescount in the last 1 year. So, the dataframe "results" is not showning it's name. When I am merging the dataframes, the salescount for TYSCO is showing NAN, but should show 0.  This is an error. and more thing is that these vales are not getting stored in an new column but the old salescount column named changes to salescount_x

Comment: For filling nan you should use fillna. I will add thia ro the answer. As for tge new column, as I mentiones in the answer, you should rename thw columns after pd.merge, that's how it works